# Sed substitute: make a group operator optional

Tags: sed, substitution

Let's say I want to use sed to substitute expressions like "foo", "foo(1 1)", "foo(42 1)" by "bar". I tried :

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/foo([0-9]\+ [0-9]\+)\{0,1\}/bar/g' input.file
```

But only replaced expressions with parenthesis after foo, not foo with no parenthesis.

Do you have any idea why ?

Example of I wish:

INPUT

```
foo
foo(236 124)
```

OUPUT

```
bar
bar
```

Comment: add sample input along with lines to be not changed inside code blocks so that formatting is preserved.. also add expected output for clarity.. `foo` is not replaced because the `{0,1}` you used will apply only to `)`.. you need to surround entire expression after foo within `\(\)`

Comment: and you can use `\?` instead of `\{0,1\}`

Comment: \? is only for one character I believe

Comment: it applies to grouping too.. it is a quantifier just like `\{0,1\}` ... `* ` and `+` can be used as well

Comment: I tried with \? sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/foo\([0-9]\+ [0-9]\+\)\?/bar/g' input.file but it only replaced foo(236 124) not foo without parenthesis.

Comment: `echo 'foobar "foo", "foo(1 1)"' | sed 's/foo\(([0-9]\+ [0-9]\+)\)\?//g'` works for me on GNU sed.. anyway you got an answer that worked for you

Comment: Thank you Sundeep, I forgot one parenthesis block, that is why it was not working. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/foo\(([0-9]\+ [0-9]\+)\)\{0,1\}/bar/g' file
           ^                  ^
           Here, I have added grouping. So that, {0,1} would work exactly.
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed 's/foo\(([0-9]\+ [0-9]\+)\)\{0,1\}/bar/g' file
bar
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/foo(\([0-9]+ [0-9]+\))?/bar/' file
```